# Plone: Redirecting Generic Views on AJAX call

Tags: ajax, redirect, view, plone

I have an AJAX call to the edit view of a content element "bar"

```
http://foo/bar/edit
```

that is rendered in an overlay. After editing the overlay closes
and redirects to

```
http://foo/bar
```

How do I tell the edit view (by the request or the form data) to redirect to

```
http://foo
```

after successful editing?

Any help appreciated

Volker

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible solutions.

1. Add a "redirect_to_parent" default view to the content type you edit.

from Products.Five.browser import BrowserView
from Acquisition import aq_inner

```
class RedirectToParent(BrowserView):

    def __call__(self):
        context = aq_inner(self.context).aq_explicit
        return self.context.REQUEST.RESPONSE.redirect(
            context.aq_parent.absolute_url())
```

So you're going to redirect automatically to it's parent after editing.

Disadvantage: You cannot longer access the view of this content directly, you have to register a second `detail_view`, which does not redirect you.

2. Handle the redirect with js (not working example):

```javascript
$(...).prepOverlay({
    subtype: 'ajax',
    filter: "#content",
            formselector: 'form',
            closeselector: '[name="form.button.cancel"]',
            config: {
                onClose: function(e, overlay) {
            // Implement redirect / reload
        }
    }
});
```

imho you should open the overlay already from it's parent, so it should be enough to just close the overlay an reload the necessary parts in the `onClose` event.